# best captcha for spring?

Tags: java, spring, captcha

Trying to implement captcha with spring framework. 
I'm searching to find a good one. 
Different users have different opinions. 
Any idea which works best with spring?

What is the advantage of JCaptcha over recaptcha ?

Comment: SimpleCaptcha works well. I like it but it's a personal opinion.

Comment: Hi,

 I sujest recapcha. [ReCapcha][1]


  [1]: http://www.google.com/recaptcha it's the best capcha available in web

Answer (score 4):

http://parasjain.net/2008/11/11/jcaptcha-with-spring/

It contains instructions on its use to, not the most complex captcha, but it should be enough to throw bots off. Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: It is JCaptcha!

Answer (score 1):

[jCaptcha](http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/) , which is [easily configurable with Spring](https://jcaptcha.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/general/pages/1212457/JCaptcha+and+the+SpringFramework)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [JCaptcha and Spring](https://jcaptcha.atlassian.net/wiki/display/general/JCaptcha+and+the+SpringFramework). It nicely outlines how to configure it using your bean definitions in Spring.

Though Google would have given [this answer](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jcaptcha%20and%20spring) too.

Answer (score 0):

JCaptcha works really well with Spring Check these links out:

https://jcaptcha.atlassian.net/wiki/display/general/JCaptcha+and+the+SpringFramework

[How to INtegrate JCaptcha with spring](http://parasjain.net/2008/11/11/jcaptcha-with-spring/)